# Adding a value based on existing ID

Tags: php, mysql

I found an `addrecord.php` which I've edited to add value based on an existing `id`, this `addrecord.php` is used to add values to another column which has an existing record already,

Sample, from the table below, Column1 and Column2 already have an existing value and I want to edit the table by adding a value to Column3 which is New3, but it does not seem to be updating the table.

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4

Exist1  | Exist2  | New3    | New4
```

I have tried to use the edit option instead to add the record based on existing `id` but the issue is still the same, not adding new records.

Here is my HTML,

```
<tr>
<td>New3:<strong><span style="color: #ff0000;">*</span></strong></td>
<td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="new3" style="width: 220px;" value=""/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>new4:<span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>*</strong></span></td>
<td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="new4" style="width: 220px;" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>" readonly="readonly"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>new5:<span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>*</strong></span></td>
<td colspan="2"><select name="new5" style="width: 224px;">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Please select...</option>
                <option value="New5Option">New5Option</option>
                <option value="New5Option2">New5Option2</option>
                <option value="New5Option3">New5Option3</option>
                <option value="New5Option4">New5Option4</option>
                </select></td>
</tr>
```

Here is my PHP,

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// get the form data
$id = $_POST['id'];
$new3 = $_POST['new3'];
$new4 = htmlentities($_POST['new4'], ENT_QUOTES);
$new5 = htmlentities($_POST['new5'], ENT_QUOTES);

// check that firstname and lastname are both not empty
if ($new3 == '' || $new4 == '' || $new5 == '')
{
// if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
$error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
renderForm($new3, $new4, new5, $id);
}
else
{
// insert the new record into the database
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT testtable (new3, new4, new5) VALUES (?, ?, ?) WHERE id=?"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("sssi", $new3, $new4, $new5, $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
// show an error if the query has an error
else
{
echo "ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement.";
}

// redirect the user
header("Location: new_statuslist.php");
}

}
// if the form hasn't been submitted yet, show the form
else
{
renderForm();
}

// close the mysqli connection
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: A `WHERE` clause is not valid as part of a a SQL `INSERT ... VALUES` statement. A SQL `INSERT` statement adds a row (or rows) to a table. Use a SQL `UPDATE` statement to modify rows that already exist. (MySQL also provides a special `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement which can be convenient for some uses cases.)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, it seems it always performs an `insert`. If you want to update an existing row then you need to execute query like this:

`update table set Column3 = ?, Column4 = ?, Column5 = ? where Column1 = ? and Column2 = ?`

It will update the values, and give you the count of records updated. If you want to insert if the record does not exist then, you can check the record count and execute the insert query if it's 0.

Comment: I've also tried this `UPDATE` but its still not updating the record,
`if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE testtable SET new3 = ?, new4 = ?, new5 = ?, comments = ? WHERE id=?"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("ssssi", $new3, $new4, $new5, $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();`

Comment: Can you check the values of param passed to that query? Maybe it's not able to find a record and hence, not updating it.

Comment: This is good now, thanks for checking though, my bad I accidentally deleted the `if (isset($_GET['id']))` thus its not updating the record.